# Example of open source tool planned with UML

Tags: modeling, uml

I'm looking for open source software that use UML modeling to present own structure. Basically I need good UML model of popular software, at best it should be 4+1 model. Google haven't helped me with this. Maybe someone has good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **StarUML** is an open source project to develop fast, flexible, extensible, featureful, and freely-available UML/MDA platform running on Win32 platform. The goal of the StarUML project is to build a software modeling tool and also platform that is a compelling replacement of commercial UML tools such as Rational Rose, Together and so on. (from: old projects of [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/v1), this project has been discontinued).

The good news is StarUML starts the new project (since long time no updates).

[**StarUML 2**](http://staruml.io/) is new project from *MKLab* as the next version of **StarUML v1**. The new version is compatible with **UML 2.x** standard and supports totally 11 kinds of UML diagrams. StarUML is available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X now.

Taken from [StarUML docs](http://staruml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling-with-uml/organizing-project.html):

You can start a modeling project by selecting a template. To start a project with a template, **select File | New From Template | TemplateName**. StarUML supports 4 default templates:

- UMLMinimal - A single model with UML Standard Profile.
- UMLConventional - Use Case Model, Analysis Model, Design Model,
- Implementation Model, and Deployment Model with UML Standard Profile.
- 4+1 View Model - [Pilippe Kruchten’s 4+1 Architectural View Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_architectural_view_model).
- Rational : Approach of Rational Rose Tool.

If you don’t want to use pre-defined templates, you need to make your own project structure.

StarUML 2 is **free** to **download**, **no time limit for evaluation**, a **license should be purchased** for continued use. I usually draw my UML diagram with this tool. For any information, let's take a look the [main site](http://staruml.io/)!